# Single Page Application Input box not showing in ie 8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, hottowel, durandal-2.0

In my Single Page App, I use Durandal and knockout.  I have a simple input box.  That input box shows up fine in Chrome, NOT in IE 8.  Any idea why?

view-

```
                    <b>Client Name:</b><input data-bind="value: clientName" />
                        <a title="Search for Client." data-bind="    click: SearchClients" class="btn btn-mini" style="vertical-align: top; line-height: 27px; font-size: 11px">Search  </a>
```

viewmodel-

```
 define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system', 'plugins/router', 'services/CertificateDataService', 'controls/Lucas', 'services/ErrorLoggingDataService'],
function (logger, system, router, CertificateDataService, Lucas, ErrorLoggingDataService) {
    var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Client Search',
    clientName: ko.observable(''),
    selectClient: function (tab) {
        try {
            alert('here');
        }
        catch (err) {
            //var err = eval("(" + err.message + ")");
            amplify.store("ErrorDetails", err.message + ", vm selectTab function");
            ErrorLoggingDataService.LogErrorSvc(err);
        }

    },
    SearchClients: function (tab) {
        try {
            alert(tab);
        }
        catch (err) {
            //var err = eval("(" + err.message + ")");
            amplify.store("ErrorDetails", err.message + ", vm selectTab function");
            ErrorLoggingDataService.LogErrorSvc(err);
        }

    },
};

return vm;

function activate() {
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: seems to work in Fiddle.  ugh!

Comment: : ) The reason I asked is because what you posted above *does* work in fiddle for all browsers.  There is probably something else you aren't showing that is causing your issue.  Have you checked the console for any errors or broken bindings?

Comment: thanks pw kad.  seeing it working in fiddle got me going in another and right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our graphics designer had put display: none for input style.  Not being aware of that I thought it was a problem with IE 8.  Not the case.  Simple style issue.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 is sensitive to trailing commas.  Towards the bottom when you're done defining the SearchClients method, you have a `},` that should only be a `}`

BTW, if everything after `var vm = {` down to just before the last line was indented one more tab, it would be easier to see what the open/close curly braces belong to.